# Pass the data from one component to another component (not a child)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to pass data (on click) from one component(A) to another component(B) but A is not child of B.

Suppose there is a form component(A), where we want to fill the required fields, and after hitting continue button, we want to display all values in next component(B).

Answer (score 1):

You can use React `Portals` which allow to render a component in any place in application dom and you can pass the props from the controlling component.

Read the docs
https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

```js
render() {
  // React does *not* create a new div. It renders the children into `domNode`.
  // `domNode` is any valid DOM node, regardless of its location in the DOM.
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <YourComponent prop1={value1} prop2={value2}/>,
    domNode
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You either use react [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API or [redux](http://redux.js.org) to share state among components.

Or if you want to pass data only while navigating you can use `history.push` function and pass data in state object as below

```
history.push({pathname: 'yourlocation', state: { data: your data}})
```

And you can accesss that data in the other component using

```
this.props.history.location.state
```

Please note that you have to wrap your components using `withRouter` to get acess to history object

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Link` from `react-router-dom` to pass data.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

In the above code `state` object can be accessed in the `history` object which can be imported from `useHistory` hook from `react-router-dom`.